# PayPal REST - Shipping info and transaction ID

Tags: php, rest, paypal, transactions

Here is a simplified version of my "ExecutePayment" php file:

```
$payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $apicontext);
$execution = new PaymentExecution();
$execution->setPayerId($_GET['PayerID']);
$payment->execute($execution, $apicontext);
var_dump($payment);
```

The payment executes successfully, but the $payment variable contains no info about the customer's address, and no transaction ID. Even if I call `$payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $apicontext);` again after executing the payment, there is no useful information contained in the Payment object.
However, in the PayPal.log file, I see the customer's address, and the transaction ID. How do I access this data aside from reading the log file itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the important object is the one returned from `$payment->execute()`

PayPal's sample on github is misleading... had to go through the PayPal API code to find my fix. :P